# Why isn't value matching up?

Tags: c++

I am having a C++ console application code, which would look up for the condition and then save the text to the (.txt) file.

But the condition is not being applied here. What I have in condition is this:

```
char command[100];
cin >> command;
if (command == "save") {
    fstream file;
    file.open("C:\\Users\\AfzaalAhmad\\Documents\\text.txt");
    file << "Data you provided was as saved!";
    cout << "File Saved!";
}
else {
    cout << "Ummm, sir I think there is an error!\n" << 
    "The command you entered was: " << command;
}
```

What I am doing is, to check the command provided by the user, if the command is 'save'

```
if(command == "save")
```

then save the data to a file, in the file the data is present when I use this code:

```
if(command != "save")
```

Because the command doesnot have to be save, the code executes and gives me the data in the file that is in documents folder.

However, if the `else` block gets executed, I can still see the correct command 'save' at the end, which is being shown by the code as you can see in the code block.

[image]

You can see there, I am using the correct command, but it is not executing as `if(command == "save")` but it executing if I use this code `if(command != "save")`.

Any guidance please?

Comment: Why aren't you using a `std::string`? Using one will solve a lot of problems

Comment: When I use `std::string` it gives me an error while using `cin >> command` .. @Bojangles :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this condition

```
if (command == "save")
```

you are trying to compare character arrays. But neither C nor C++ has the comparison operator for arrays. Instead this the string literal and the array in the left part of the operation are implicitly converted to pointers to their first characters and in fact you are comparing two pointers that will be always unequal.
To compare character arrays you should use standard C function `std::strcmp` that is declared in header `<cstring>`( in C++ ) or `<string.h>` (in C)

For example

```
if ( std::strcmp( command, "save" ) == 0 )
```

Answer (score 6):

`command` and the string literal `"save"` are both arrays of `char`s. They are both being converted to pointers to the first elements (this is called array-to-pointer conversion) and you are comparing those pointers. So what you're really doing with `command == "save"` is checking if their first characters have the same address.

Instead, to compare C-style strings like you want (checking if all characters in the strings are the same), you need to use [`std::strcmp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcmp). However, a much more preferable solution in C++ is to make `command` a `std::string`, instead of an array of `char`. `std::string` supports comparison using `==`.

Comment: +1, yeah maybe that was the error here in my case..I was just comparing these arrays and thought it would do it just as it does in ASP.NET!

Answer (score 1):

Because you should use `strcmp` to compare C style strings. Or use `std::string`, which is also better in many other ways, besides being able to compare strings with `==`.

A C style string constant is just the address to some memory that holds that particular string, so when you compare `command == "save"`, then for that comparison to be true, `command` must have the same address as the constant string `"save"` - which clearly isn't the case ever.

Answer (score 1):

command is a char array, you cannot compare it to a string literal like that (you are actually comparing adresses). If you don't want to use std::string that overload the == operator you could say

```
strcmp(command, "save"); // it returns zero if equal
```

Answer (score 0):

For comparing c-strings you should use `strcmp()` function.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing the address of `command` to the address of a string literal.  They will never be the same.

Possible solutions:

- use the C library function `strcpy`: `if (0 == strcmp(command, "save"))`
- cast one to a C++ string: `if (std::string(command) == "save)`
- Use a C++14 string literal: `if (command == "save"s)`
- Store the user's input into a C++ string to begin with.

The last of these is the best option, and looks like:

```
std::string command;
cin >> command;
if (command == "save") {
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable `command` is of type `char*`, because an array in C/C++ is (basically) a pointer (and a fixed maximum array size). Since you are using C++, consider using `std::string` instead: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/string.html.

What you are using is a C-Style string, and you have to use functions such as `strcmp`, for example described here: [How do I properly compare strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8004237/how-do-i-properly-compare-strings-in-c). But that is the C-way, and, if you're writing C++, you should stick to the `std::string` class for such purposes.